# Disable the "400 Bad Request" error for missing keys in form

Tags: python, flask

The documentation for Flask [explains](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) that it will return a `400 Bad Request` error if code attempts to access a form key that does not exist.  This makes debugging difficult because the error doesn't have information about what key is missing or if something else caused the error.

Is there a way to disable the 400 error and return a "500 Internal Server Error" with a traceback in the logs instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a great solution.  At least with `Flask-restful`, but I suspect that this is the case with the `Flask-request` in general.  If you get a `400 Bad Request` back, examining the JSON response from the server will give you more data.  For example, in the Firefox development console, go to the network take, click on the request that generated the bad request, click the "Response" tab, and BAM, there's your useful debug error.  Works at least in development mode on my own server.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sure if the form contains a key, you should use `.get(key)`, which returns `None` if it is not found, rather than directly indexing it.

Typically, form validation should not raise an error at all, but should return messages about why validation failed.  Consider using a form library such as [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/) to handle validation for you, so you get nice messages instead of errors.

---

If you still want to mess with the errors rather than doing validation, you can add a custom error handler to log the exception and return a generic 500 error.

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort, BadRequestKeyError

@app.errorhandler(BadRequestKeyError)
def handle_key_error(e):
    app.logger.exception('Missing key {}'.format(e.args[0]))

    # raise a new 500 exception
    # abort doesn't work from inside an error handler
    # so simulate how Flask would handle it
    try:
        abort(500)
    except Exception as new_e:
        app.handle_user_exception(new_e)
```

Your logging setup may be different.  The app logger may require extra configuration when not in debug mode.